# issues with sqoop and hive

Tags: hive, sqoop

We are facing the following issues details as follows, please share your inputs.

1) Issue with --validate option in sqoop

if we run the sqoop command without creating a job for it, validate works. But if we create a job first, with validate option the validate doesn't seem to work.

### works with

sqoop import --connect "DB connection" --username $USER --password-file $File_Path --warehouse-dir $TGT_DIR --as-textfile --fields-terminated by '|' --lines-teriminated-by '\n' --table emp_table -m 1 --outdir $HOME/javafiles --validate

### Does not work with

sqoop job --create Job_import_emp import --connect "DB connection" --username $USER --password-file $File_Path --warehouse-dir $TGT_DIR --as-textfile --fields-terminated by '|' --lines-teriminated-by '\n' --table emp_table -m 1 --outdir $HOME/javafiles --validate

2) Issue with Hive import

If we are importing data for the first time in hive, it becomes imperative to create hive table ( hive internal), so we keep "--create-hive-table" in sqoop command.

Even thouhg if i keep "--create-hive-table" option, Is there any way to skip create table step in hive while importing, if the table is already exists.

Thanks
Sheik

Answer (score 0):

Sqoop allows `--validate` option only for `sqoop import` and `sqoop export` commands.

From the official [Sqoop User guide](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.3/SqoopUserGuide.html#validation), the validation has these limitations,

- all-tables option
- free-form query option
- Data imported into Hive or HBase table
- import with --where argument

No, the table check cannot be skip if `--create-hive-table` option is set, the job will fail if the target table exists.